# Nothing shows in Personal Settings --> Connected Accounts in sandbox org

Tags: sandbox, einstein-activity-capture, lightning-sync-configurations

After successfully setting up Einstein Activity Capture (for Google) on my production org,
I then assigned the Standard Einstein Activity Capture permission set to a user.

In the production org I was able to connect the user's Google account via `Personal Settings --> Connected Accounts`. The user's Google calendar successfully synced its events to the user's calendar.

[image]

I then created a sandbox and set up Einstein Activity Capture as on the production org. The same user was copied to the sandbox org, as was the permission set.

In the sandbox org no events show. When I go to `Personal Settings --> Connected Accounts`, nothing shows, notably the `New Account` button.
[image]
How do I connect the user's Google account in the sandbox org so that they can view their Google calendar events as on the production org?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Considerations for Setting Up Einstein Activity Capture](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.aac_limitations.htm&type=5) notes the following about Multiple Salesforce Orgs:

> **Setting up the same user to sync across multiple orgs isn’t supported**.
> While we recommend testing in a sandbox org before rolling out
> Einstein Activity Capture, remove users from sandbox sync
> configurations before adding users to production configurations.

I'm not sure why you're looking to set up this user in a sandbox, but I'd recommend an admin being set up in sandbox to sync (and not set up in production) for testing changes if that's the use case.

Comment: Yes, once I removed the user from the production org's configuration in `Personal Settings --> Connected Accounts`, I was able to connect their account in the sandbox org.