# Connected Accounts in Personal Settings

Tags: community, sales

Connected Accounts does not appear in Personal Settings.
What should I do?
Thanks & best regards

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. As is, I don't think there's enough detail here for anyone to really be able to help you. You should [edit] your question to provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

Connected Accounts Page Was Renamed.
[Connected Account](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sales_productivity_eac_connected_accounts_page_label.htm&type=5&release=232)

To help distinguish among the types of accounts that sales reps can connect to Salesforce, the Connected Accounts page, which is where users see which email and calendar accounts are connected to Salesforce, is called Email and Calendar Accounts.

Where: This change applies to Lightning Experience in Essentials, Professional, Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited editions.

Who: The Email and Calendar Accounts page is available to Einstein Activity Capture and Inbox users.

How: When users manage their connected Microsoft or Google account through features such as Einstein Activity Capture and Inbox, they go to their personal settings and then click Email and Calendar Accounts under Connected Accounts.

For more detail, refer this :- [Consideration for Connected Accounts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/348900/nothing-shows-in-personal-settings-connected-accounts-in-sandbox-org)

Comment: Thanks I know that, but don't appears. I don't know why.
I search all the settnigs and don't find it